# How to get loaded server video on iPhone

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I have following code for load server a video but it show blank white screen with big play button in middle on iPhone. Already loaded video showing in PC browsers.  How to get loaded video in iPhone. This is without using `poster` in `iframe`

CODE:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<video controls="true" src="LINK" controlsList="nodownload" preload="metadata" playsinline webkit-playsinline></video>
</div>
```

iPhone Show Video Like This,
[image]

Comment: Its possibly a format that the devices does not support - if you can provide a link to the video or an output from ffprobe that might help diagnose

Comment: But when I click it it is playing

Comment: to autoplay it needs to be muted (and have the autoplay property). you also want a poster attribute if you want to show an image

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from your comment above that the video is loading but not auto playing.

Looking at your HTML you probably just need to add the autoplay tag - e.g. as in this example:

```html
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="yourVideo.mp4">
  <source src="yourVideo.webm">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```